# How to query with a list using clojure.jdbc

Tags: jdbc, clojure

```
(sql/with-connection {... mydatabase }
    (sql/with-query-results rows [ "select * from users where email in (?)" 
       [ "bob@site.com" "mary@other.com" ] ] 
       (doseq [rows row] 
            (prn row))))
```

This will always return no result.   I've also tried using just "?" in place of "(?)"

Answer (score 2):

AFAIR you can't do this directly. Behind the scene macro `with-query-results` uses java.sql.PreparedStatement and invokes .setObject for each parameter. So you have to write something like this

```
(sql/with-connection db
  (sql/with-query-results rs
    [(str "select * from users where email in ("
          (apply
           str
           (interpose ", " (map #(str "\"" % "\"")
                                ["bob@site.com" "mary@other.com"]))) ")")]
    ...))
```

to generate already prepared sql string with "in" parameters: `"select * from users where email in (\"bob@site.com\", \"mary@other.com\")"`.

The better way is just to use one of clojure sql libraries like sqlkorma.

Comment: This can lead to SQL injection

Comment: You're right. It's not the full solution and It need to be improved or replaced by existing library.

Answer (score 0):

Now in 2020, you can do this without string concatenation, at least in postgres.

Extend the ISQLParameter protocol like this:

```
; This allows us to use clojure arrays as query parameters for JDBC.
; Thus, we don't need to do string concatenation to make IN clauses.
(extend-protocol clojure.java.jdbc/ISQLParameter
  Sequential
  ; Important: Sometimes you have to explicitly specify the type of array like ?::text[].
  (set-parameter [v ^PreparedStatement stmt ^long i]
    (let [conn (.getConnection stmt)
          meta (.getParameterMetaData stmt)
          type-name (.getParameterTypeName meta i)]
      (if-let [elem-type (when (= (first type-name) \_) (apply str (rest type-name)))]
        (.setObject stmt i (.createArrayOf conn elem-type (to-array v)))
        (.setObject stmt i v)))))
```

Then you can run queries like

```
(jdbc/query db/db ["select 'banana' = ANY(?) as banana_included, 
                           'apple' = ANY(?) as apple_included" 
                   ["banana" "potato"] ["banana" "potato"]])
```

The `= ANY(array)` syntax does the same job as an `in` clause - as far as I know `IN` clauses are converted to the `= ANY(array)` internally in postgres - don't quote me on that though.